# Reactjs/JS - Confused about the object/ what is being created

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise

I have just switched over from studying Java to studying Javascript and I am trying to learn React and Redux right now. I am having some confusion with how some objects seem to be created in this tutorial I have been following on YouTube. This tut has so far just covered logging in and signing into a webpage.

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  user: {
    login: credentials =>
      axios.post("/api/auth", { credentials }).then(res => res.data.user),
    signup: user =>
      axios.post("/api/users", { user }).then(res => res.data.user),
    confirm: token =>
      axios.post("/api/auth/confirmation", { token }).then(res => res.data.user)
  }
};
```

This is what I am understanding from this code currently:
`axios` is imported so that various HTTP requests can be made. A `user` object is created that contains an array of 3 objects (functions?) : `login`, `signup` and `confirm`. In `login` object, an arrow function is used to pass `credentials` as the parameter into the `axios` object's post function. A promise is then called where the response data is passed into ???  which returns a `res.data.user` object.

I don't understand what the `res.data.user` object is, why is it described in such form with the dot separation instead of just something like `responseDataObject`?

This next piece of code is the 'action' part of the app (Redux) where the api.js is imported. Here 2 of the functions are exported into a new function which is called depending on the state of the user.... I don't think the other parts are relevant to talk about because I understand that programming logic. What I don't understand is how and why the `res.data.object` is returned like that. Where is the `data` part coming from? Is that arbitrarily described?

I am clearing missing something here, I've been watching some videos to try to understand what's going on but I think it might be a simple reason best described here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few terminologies you are using or understanding incorrectly. I think it is important to understand them before dive too deep into React.

First, Object:

An object has key/value pairs.

```
{
    fruit: "apple"
}
```

> that contains an array of 3 objects (functions?)

This would be incorrect. Since array's syntax is `[]`. What you were describing is element or member or key.

Next part is about the promise in Javascript. You have this code. `axios.post("/api/auth", { credentials }).then(res => res.data.user),` This is basically saying once you call the `api` with that `url`, some data will come back(we stored in `res`). But the `res` is an object in this case.

If you console log `res`, you will get an object like this:

```
{
  ...
  key1: "something",
  key2: "something else",
  data: {
     ...
     user: { //some info about the user}
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

What you want is the data inside of `res`, more specifically you want the user's value. So to access it, you want to use `res.data.user`.

Hopefully, this answers some of your questions, but there is a lot to talk about. You should read more on js's object.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to JS world :)

> A user object is created that contains an array of 3 objects
>   (functions?)

Yep it's just 3 simple functions

> A promise is then called where the response data is passed into ???
>   which returns a res.data.user object.

Promise is resolved (then function called) when server response status 2** and inside then `res` is just simple object witch is come from server (status, headers, response body), here is docs describing what res contains: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema

So inside res.data - client assumed that server responds with user object which contains some user data (example server returns json `{user: {id: 1, name: 'Hary'}}`)

> I don't understand what the res.data.user object is, why is it
>   described in such form with the dot separation instead of just
>   something like responseDataObject?

You just accessing object properties (example res = `{data: {user: {id: 1, name: 'Hary'}}}`)
So this code `.then(res => res.data.user)` just an simple helper to return user and not whole response from server, here how you can use it `user.login({login: 'cool_user', password: 'qwerty'}).then(user => console.log(user.id))` so if I assumed that sever retunrs this data you got into console user id after success login

Answer (score 0):

One thing not covered in the other posts is this syntax:

```
export default {
    // ...
};
```

This exports an object from the `api.js` file. This object is not assigned to a variable or given a name here. Instead, you do that when you import:

```
import api from 'api.js';
```

Now in the file with this import, the name `api` refers to the object exported from `api.js`. So you can do things like `api.user.login(credentials)` to call one of the functions defined iniside this object.